# Send push message to Android without sound

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, push-notification, salesforce-sdk-android

just wondering am i able to send push notification to android device without notification sound? Like silent push or just without sound it doesn't matter. I don't see any documentation writing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the Notification Channel and/or you can customize the Notification.  It is well documented [HERE](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html), [HERE](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/custom-channels.html), and [HERE](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications/-notification-customization-options/index.html).

Additionally, the message can be configured in the MarketingCloud UI to have a sound of `NONE`.

Comment: Hey @BillMote, thanks for reply. Unfortunately marking message to have sound of NONE doesn't work. The sound still plays. Can I access any parameter in NotificationMessage which tells, that NONE was selected for sound?

Comment: `sound` is part of the NotificationMessage you receive.  Your notification channel is controlling the audio.  See documentation link in my answer.